# Href only works when clicking on div text and not whole div

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I can only click my div if I click on its text, I would like the whole div to be clickable, thank you.
I have attached the code snippet, I have read that the issue is in my div container which is class all in css but I couldn't spot out where the issue is exactly.
Any help would be appreciated , thank you so much !

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  perspective: 10px;
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(20deg);
  will-change: perspective;
  perspective-origin: center center;
  transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
  justify-content: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.all:hover {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transition: all 1.3s ease-in;
  transform: perspective(10000px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.all:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.all:hover>div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.all:hover .explainer {
  opacity: 0;
}

.left,
.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(100, 100, 255, .4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #58d;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.left:hover,
.center:hover,
.right:hover,
.lefter:hover,
.righter:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(100, 100, 255, .6);
  background-color: #ccf;
}

.text {
  transform: translateY(30px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  will-change: transform;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(100, 100, 255, .6);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-30px) translateZ(-25px) rotateY(-5deg);
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/creative_draw-512.png);
}

.center {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png);
}

.explainer {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #303050;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center top, #cce, #33a);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <div class="text">Profile</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Then you have to wrap the whole `<div>` by the `<a>` like 
`<a href="https://www.google.com" ><div class="left"><div class="text">Profile</div></div></a>`

Comment: If I do so , the left div doesn't even show up you can try it by modifying cod snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a little script that listens for click on the `.all` element.

```css
.all {
  cursor:pointer;
  display: flex;
  perspective: 10px;
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(20deg);
  will-change: perspective;
  perspective-origin: center center;
  transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
  justify-content: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.all:hover {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transition: all 1.3s ease-in;
  transform: perspective(10000px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.all:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.all:hover>div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.all:hover .explainer {
  opacity: 0;
}

.left,
.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(100, 100, 255, .4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #58d;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.left:hover,
.center:hover,
.right:hover,
.lefter:hover,
.righter:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(100, 100, 255, .6);
  background-color: #ccf;
}

.text {
  transform: translateY(30px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  will-change: transform;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(100, 100, 255, .6);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-30px) translateZ(-25px) rotateY(-5deg);
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/creative_draw-512.png);
}

.center {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png);
}

.explainer {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #303050;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center top, #cce, #33a);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="all">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <div class="text">Profile</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
    </div>
  </div>
    <script>
    var all = document.querySelector('.all');
    all.addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
    });
    </script>
</body>
```